# qt QStandardItemModel data() not being called

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I have very simple, custom model derived from `QStandardItemModel`. Functions `rowCount` and `columnCount` are called several times whereas none of the remaining functions, in particular `data()` is never called. I cannot find the reason.

```
#include <IBAdditions/IB_events.h>

#include <QtGui/QStandardItemModel>
#include <QtGui/QStandardItem>
#include <QtCore/QtCore>

#include <vector>

/**
 * model which allows for display 
 * of available data streams as tickers
 */
class TickerDisplayModel : public QStandardItemModel {

Q_OBJECT
 public:
     TickerDisplayModel(std::vector<IBAdditions::ContractEvent> availableTickers, QObject *parent = 0);
     int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const ;
     int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
     QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
     QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
     bool setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
     Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex & index) const;
 private:
     int m_;
     int n_;
     std::vector<IBAdditions::ContractEvent>& availableTickers_;
 signals:
     void editCompleted(const QString &);
};
```

how this is called:

```
SubscribeToDataGUI::SubscribeToDataGUI(QWidget* parent) : QDialog(parent) {
    widget_.setupUi(this);
    IBAdditions::ContractEvent c;
    c.symbol = "EUR"; c.currency = "USD"; c.event_ = IBAdditions::TickPrice;
    availableTickers_.push_back(c);
    model_.reset(new TickerDisplayModel(availableTickers_));
    widget_.listView->setModel(model_.get());
    widget_.listView->show();
}
```

Comment: Do `rowCount()` and `columnCount()` functions return non-zero values?

Comment: yes, they do return 2 and 3 respectively

Comment: Well, another point: you use QStandardItemModel, however I do not see that you explicitly add QStandardItems to it. Docs say that: "QStandardItemModel provides a classic item-based approach to working with the model. **The items in a QStandardItemModel are provided by QStandardItem**.". Maybe it worth to try the same, but using QAbstractTableModel, which better fit to what you do, IMO?

Comment: yes, it seems you cannot use data() in QStandardItemModel to plot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to subclass data in QStandardItemModel.

I just try change my own QAbstractItemModel to QStandardItemModel and data is not called either.

Try to use QAbstractItemModel.
I think you have implemented almost everything you need to use QAbstractItemModel

You need to implement index and parent. Since you have no hiearchical model, parent should always return invalid index.

It can be implemented like this:

```
    QModelIndex TickerDisplayModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
       return hasIndex(row, column, parent) ? createIndex(row, column, 0) : QModelIndex();
    }

    QModelIndex TickerDisplayModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
    {
        return QModelIndex(); // since no hiearchy model, this should always return invalid index
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the reason, you have to add items using QStandardItem and appendRow() or change model to derive from abstract